# Connection Refused redis master slave with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I have a master slave set up on ports 3824(master) and 3825(slave). However, when I shutdown master, the read operation gives a connection refused exception. Below is my configuration. How can I ensure that even if I kill master, I'm still reading from slave. Where did i go wrong.

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory redisFactory() {

LettuceClientConfiguration config = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().readFrom(ReadFrom.SLAVE_PREFERRED).buld();
RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost",3825);
    LettuceConnectionFactory fact = new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig, config);
    return fact;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To support *high-availability* within your application, you might need to implement the [redis-sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel).

Redis Sentinel when passed to `RedisSentinelConfiguration` act as a bridge b/w your application and the redis master-slave nodes running as in a group of servers.

It will mainly act as a configuration provider. If a failover occurs, Sentinels will report the new address

[Spring Data Redis Sentinel Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:sentinel):

```
/**
 * Lettuce
 */
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
  RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration()
  .master("mymaster")
  .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26379)
  .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26380);
  return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig);
}
```

Upon master failure event, when the slave is promoted as master, all write requests will be routed to the newly elected master.

Comment: Should i setup sentinal seperately at the redis server level to communicate with springboot

Comment: @user3310115: yes

Comment: Where can i find a guide on this. I have a basic master slave setup. How do I proceed from there

Comment: this guide looks good: https://medium.com/@amila922/redis-sentinel-high-availability-everything-you-need-to-know-from-dev-to-prod-complete-guide-deb198e70ea6